# Retarget Windows Phone 8 app to Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

As many of you may know, Microsoft will be releasing the new Windows Phone 10 operating system to current Windows Phone 8.1 users.

I was wondering whether it will be possible to retarget Windows Phone 8/8.1 apps to Windows Phone 10 and if so how.

I couldn't really find any information on this so I will greatly appreciate any information on how to do this.

PS. My app is written in C# and XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is too early to speak about the way WP 8 application migration to WP 10.

Work on WP 10 still actively underway and many changes occur in operating system (see Windows Insider).

Exactly, we can say that all the applications created by template WP 8.1 (RT, but not SilverLigth 8.1) will work on WP 10.
I've tried a few of their applications WP 8.1 for Windows Phone 10 (Insider) and have not noticed problems.